# Calculator price form in jQuery

Tags: jquery, calculator

I'm working on a calculator in jQuery where you can have a variable number of users and locations. So I have two dropdowns where you can select your number of users and number of locations.

You can choose between 3 packages: go, pro and expert. My example below will be for the go package.

The Go package has a starting price per month of **130 euro**. This includes **1 user** and **1 location**.

**Here are my 2 dropdowns:**

```
<select class="js-users">
                <?php 
                    $numUsers = 1;
                    while($numUsers <= 15) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $numUsers; ?>"><?php echo $numUsers; ?></option>
                <?php 
                    $numUsers ++;
                    } 
                ?>
</select>

<select class="js-locations">
                <?php 
                    $numLocations = 1;
                    while($numLocations <= 15) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $numLocations; ?>"><?php echo $numLocations; ?></option>
                <?php 
                    $numLocations ++;
                    } 
                ?>
</select>
```

- Default price go package = 130 euro (this included 1 user and 1 - location).
- One extra user = 15 euro
- One extra location = 75 euro

By default 1 user and 1 location is selected. When you change the number of users to, for example, 2 users, the total price will be 130 + (15 * 2) = 160 euro

And when you change the number of locations to 3, the new total price will be 130 + (15 * 2) + (75 * 3) = 385

With my code below, the always overwrites the previous selected values.

**My jQuery code looks like this:**

```
jQuery(function($){

    //define the base price per package
    var priceGo = 130,
        pricePro = 295,
        priceExpert = 495;

    //define total var
    var priceTotal = 0;

    //multipliers
    var priceUser = 15,
        priceLocation = 75,
        numUsers = 1,
        numLocations = 1;


    $('.js-calculator-go .js-users').on('change', function(e){

        priceTotal = priceGo + (priceUser * $(this).val());

        console.log(priceTotal);

    });


    $('.js-calculator-go .js-locations').on('change', function(e){

        priceTotal = priceGo + (priceLocation * $(this).val());

        console.log(priceTotal);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you aren't taking into account the selected value in the other dropdown when you make each calculation.

It would make more sense to hand off the calculation to a single function which is called from both "change" events, and which takes into account the current selected values in each dropdown when re-calculating. This way you don't duplicate any calculation logic, and the logic isn't directly tied to the UI elements which feed it:

```
//define the base price per package
var priceGo = 130,
    pricePro = 295,
    priceExpert = 495;

//define total var
var priceTotal = 0;

//multipliers
var priceUser = 15,
    priceLocation = 75;

$('.js-calculator-go .js-locations, .js-calculator-go .js-users').on('change', calculatePrice);

function calculatePrice()
{
    priceTotal = priceGo + (priceUser * $('.js-calculator-go .js-users').val()) + (priceLocation * $('.js-calculator-go .js-locations').val());
    console.log(priceTotal);
}
```

Comment: almost. If I only select 2 users and I keep location on 1, you must "ignore" the extra 75 euro for the location because by default you already have 1 location included. Now it's alway + 75 * x

Comment: in that case I would suggest to alter the default priceGo value so that it doesn't include it. i.e. `priceGo = 55` as the initial value. That way you keep the calculation nice and simple still. Presumably it's the same issue for selecting 1 user as well?